# error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat when pip install pyspider win-10 32bits python 3.5+

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-10

[image: error]

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat when pip install pyspider win-10 32bits python 3.5+

Comment: Don't link without explanation to an image - it may not last the same amount of time as your question.

Comment: This has been answered so often.  Have you done any searching at all?  Tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

try prebuilt binaries packages: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

via http://docs.pyspider.org/en/latest/Frequently-Asked-Questions/#does-pyspider-work-with-windows